# Kernel for Gaussian Blur

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to make a kernel for GaussianBlur, but I have no idea how to do it.
I have tried this, but it throws an error.

```
    import cv2 as cv
    import numpy as np
    
    img = cv.imread('lena_gray.bmp')
    
    x = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2], [1, 2, 1]])
#x2 = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 4, -1], [0, -1, 0]]) I also need the ability to use other types of kernels like this one
    img_rst = cv.GaussianBlur(img, kernel=x)
    cv.imwrite('result.jpg', img_rst)
```

Is it possible to change kernels? I have been looking for a solution, but without result.

Comment: You can convolve the image with a custom kernel via the `filter2d` function: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d4/dbd/tutorial_filter_2d.html

Comment: "an error" means you have to post the error

Comment: Can you also share the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed the Opencv's inbuilt method of Gaussian blurring and custom kernel filtering method. Let us see the two methods below:

First load the original image

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img_path = 'Lena.png'
image = plt.imread(img_path)
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image]

If you want to use the inbuilt method, then you do not need to make the kernel yourself. Just define its size (size=11x11 below):

```
img_blur = cv2.blur(src=image, ksize=(11,11))
plt.imshow(img_blur)
```

[image]

If you want to use your own kernel. Use `filter2D` method:

```
blur_kernel = np.ones((11, 11), np.float32) / 121
kernel_blurred = cv2.filter2D(src=image, ddepth=-1, kernel=blur_kernel)
plt.imshow(kernel_blurred)
```

[image]

Comment: cv2.blur is not a Gaussian Blur. It is a uniform blur. For Gaussian blur, use cv2.GaussianBlur